# Samsung Galaxy S3 - after AT&T over the wire update - google search doesn't find installed apps

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-3, att, google-search

I just purchased a Galaxy S III from AT&T, and only after a few days, I got a pushed, forced update from AT&T (not stating what it does, just "**AT&T Software update**" version: "**V3_1205_2_2**")

I didn't notice any change for a few hours, until I wanted to search for an app (menu - search)

Up until the update (still innocent till proven guilty, but looks more than circumstantial evidence) as in any android phone, the built in google search would search and find all installed apps,

However after that update (and again, it could be something else, but I can't think what it is) it stopped working. Google search (which is the built in device search) only shows web results and bookmarks

Am I the only one experiencing it? if so I'll just return it to AT&T and get another, as much as re-installing everything gives me a headache just thinking about it.

If I'm not the only one, then is it indeed a bug in AT&T's anonymous, rude, forcing itself on you, update?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Galaxy S3 dumb search update feature confirmed by Samsung, it’s because of Apple

Read more [here:](http://www.androidauthority.com/galaxy-s3-dumb-search-update-feature-confirmed-samsung-its-because-apple-101371/)

It has been removed by Samsung working closely with Google and has been removed from carriers like [Sprint](http://www.androidauthority.com/sprint-galaxy-s3-security-update-dumbs-down-search-avoid-apple-injunction-100410/) as well. Apple pattented the universal search and was able to ban Galaxy Nexus in US. As a precaution Samsung and Google took the decision.

> One of the two injunctions Apple obtained in the U.S., even though stayed on the second appeal, affected the Galaxy Nexus and was based on an Apple patent describing a “unified search” technology, which is currently used by various mobile devices. The Galaxy Nexus made use of that technology – the Google Search app displayed local results (stuff on the phone) and web results, when the user performed a search – and that’s one of the things that got it into temporary trouble.

**Solution:**

But you can get the search back by installing old quick search app. You've to follow [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1762570&highlight=universal+search) post in xda-developers.com for that. If you're not rooted you've to replace it every time you restart the phone ;).

**Update from Samsung**

> Samsung has updated the software for the Galaxy S III as a precautionary measure to ensure that U.S. consumers may enjoy using our innovative products without interruption

Comment: So there is no way for me to search for apps? just apps?  Android 2.1 had a simple "search in apps" feature, which only searched apps, no web results, no patent infringement, they removed it. I guess if I wrote a new app manager with search in apps only I would make millions now on google play

Comment: Also - "used by variable mobile devices". It's used ANYWHERE. it's used in windows 7 search omnibox, it's used in Ubuntu, it's used in. well, Google... (searches places, addresses, and even apps) someone needs to change the legislation on software patents quickly, before someone makes a patent on typing on a keyboard and take it away from me

Answer (score 2):

For the record (mostly for foreign googlers):

A working solution has been proposed here:
[Is there an app for searching installed apps? (Dumb Search alternative)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25999/is-there-an-app-for-searching-installed-apps-dumb-search-alternative/26013#26013)