# Android Jelly Bean: fix search button

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, 4.1-jelly-bean, buttons, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Samsung Galaxy S3 - after AT&T over the wire update - google search doesn’t find installed apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25964/samsung-galaxy-s3-after-att-over-the-wire-update-google-search-doesnt-find)

I just upgraded my Nexus S from Android 4.0.something (I forget the subversion) to Android 4.1.1.

The magnifying glass button used to be really useful -- it would trigger a search function within whatever app I was using. For example pressing it within the Maps app would search for a place, or pressing it within the Facebook app would search for a friend.

But now, the magnifying glass button launches a google search no matter what the context is! This is extremely annoying and makes a lot of apps harder to use, especially Maps.

How can I use a setting or a patch to revert the magnifying glass button to its old behavior?

Comment: I can't answer your real question, but most apps have a "search" item accessible from their menu, which you typically get at by tapping the tower-of-three-squares button.

Comment: @roxan: This is seemingly not a dupe of the linked question (which is about 'dropping apps in the universal search' for apple patent reasons. Here the question is about the behaviour of the search button 'former: inapp search vs. now: send active app to background and launch google search')